# Find an element by partial ID and then find which id got selected in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So i have these items whose ids are like `#date_0`, `#date_1`, etc.

Here is my script :

```
$('[id*="date_"]').bind('change', function(event) {
    var hour_id = $('[id*="date_"]').val();
    console.log(hour_id);
});
```

what I want is that if I change `#date_5`, I get its value. But I am getting only `#date_0`'s value.
What am I missing here?

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest you use common classes to group elements, and not incremental `id` attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `this` to get the current element that was changed:

```
var hour_id = $(this).val();
```

When you are inside a callback in jQuery - `this` is a reference to the element that triggered the current event.
In your code - `this` is the element that was just changed.

Check this example:

```js
$('[id*="date_"]').bind('change', function(event) {
  var hour_id = $(this).val();
  console.log(hour_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date_0" />
<input id="date_1" />
```